# When using translate rails 4.1 sets data value incorrectly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

I'm saving some translation data in the data attribute of a DOM element.

```
<input type='button' id=admin-button data-add= <%=t :Add_Category%> data-save= <%=t :Save%> value= <%=t :Add_Category%>
```

unfortunately when the translation file value has a space such as Add_Category:"Add Category"

I get

```
data-add="Add" category=""
```

instead of

```
data-add="add category"
```

it works if i do it without the translation in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put double quote the around the erb tags? or better use the rails helpers, maybe button_tag

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-button_tag

```
<%= button_tag t(:add_category), 
  id: "admin-button",
  data: {
    add: t(:add_category),
    save: t(:save)
  }  
%>
```

this renders a `<button>` if you must have `input type="button"`, maybe this would work

```
<%= content_tag :input, 
  t(:add_category), 
  type: "button",
  id: "admin-button",
  data: {
    add: t(:add_category),
    save: t(:save)
  }  
%>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag

Also I recommend using all lower case with underscores - i.e. `:add_category` vs `:Add_Category` - it is more in the ruby style

Comment: All thee methods take care of the space issue. I went with the quotes around the erb, since i was using the <input to get a button where the label was defined by the value field.  That way I can easily change the label of the button by reassigning to the value field, hence the data-save and data-add .